# Why are my if-up.d scripts running before DHCP(v6) has completed?

Tags: debian, raspbian, dhcp, network-interface, ipv6

I'm using DHCP and have both IPv4 and IPv6. I want to run a script that updates an IPv6 DDNS service when my network is configured.

I created a script at `/etc/network/if-up.d/update_dns` however this script fails with a DNS resolution error (`curl: (6) Could not resolve host: dynv6.com`). The logs seem to show it's running before the IPv6 DHCP is finished. I think maybe this is because IPv4 is ready and the scripts fire.

Is there somewhere else I should put scripts that require IPv6? There are [many answers](https://serverfault.com/a/182136/38366) that suggest `if-up.d` is the correct place?

I'm using Raspbian Jessie Lite, which already has `Slow Boot` (a script at `/etc/systemd/system/dhcpcd.service.d/wait.conf` that waits for DHCP) [which fixed similar issues previously with things running before the network was ready](https://github.com/RPi-Distro/repo/issues/24).

I've included logs of anything including network/dhcp/eth0 below.

```
Apr  6 20:49:58 raspberrypi systemd[1]: Starting LSB: Raise network interfaces....
Apr  6 20:49:58 raspberrypi networking[223]: Configuring network interfaces...* Hostname was NOT found in DNS cache
Apr  6 20:49:58 raspberrypi networking[223]: % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
Apr  6 20:49:58 raspberrypi networking[223]: Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
Apr  6 20:49:58 raspberrypi networking[223]: 0     0    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--     0* Could not resolve host: dynv6.com
Apr  6 20:49:58 raspberrypi networking[223]: * Closing connection 0
Apr  6 20:49:58 raspberrypi networking[223]: curl: (6) Could not resolve host: dynv6.com
Apr  6 20:49:58 raspberrypi networking[223]: done.
Apr  6 20:49:58 raspberrypi systemd[1]: Started LSB: Raise network interfaces..
Apr  6 20:49:58 raspberrypi systemd[1]: Starting dhcpcd on all interfaces...
Apr  6 20:49:58 raspberrypi dhcpcd[385]: version 6.7.1 starting
Apr  6 20:49:58 raspberrypi dhcpcd[385]: dev: loaded udev
Apr  6 20:49:58 raspberrypi dhcpcd[385]: eth0: adding address fe80::1073:c87:ef15:c4a3
Apr  6 20:49:58 raspberrypi dhcpcd[385]: eth0: waiting for carrier
Apr  6 20:49:58 raspberrypi dhcpcd[385]: wlan0: waiting for carrier
Apr  6 20:50:00 raspberrypi dhcpcd[385]: eth0: carrier acquired
Apr  6 20:50:00 raspberrypi dhcpcd[385]: DUID 00:01:00:01:1e:7e:75:f4:b8:27:eb:8c:48:b0
Apr  6 20:50:00 raspberrypi dhcpcd[385]: eth0: IAID eb:8c:48:b0
Apr  6 20:50:01 raspberrypi dhcpcd[385]: eth0: rebinding lease of 192.168.0.100
Apr  6 20:50:01 raspberrypi dhcpcd[385]: eth0: soliciting an IPv6 router
Apr  6 20:50:02 raspberrypi dhcpcd[385]: eth0: Router Advertisement from fe80::c23e:fff:fe63:5170
Apr  6 20:50:02 raspberrypi dhcpcd[385]: eth0: adding address fd41:6d80:6364:0:bcdf:ae43:354b:1e46/64
Apr  6 20:50:02 raspberrypi dhcpcd[385]: eth0: adding address 2a02:c7d:2bbb:9f00:76b3:47f9:2c11:fea4/64
Apr  6 20:50:02 raspberrypi dhcpcd[385]: eth0: adding route to fd41:6d80:6364::/64
Apr  6 20:50:02 raspberrypi dhcpcd[385]: eth0: adding route to 2a02:c7d:2bbb:9f00::/64
Apr  6 20:50:02 raspberrypi dhcpcd[385]: eth0: adding default route via fe80::c23e:fff:fe63:5170
Apr  6 20:50:02 raspberrypi dhcpcd[385]: eth0: requesting DHCPv6 information
Apr  6 20:50:06 raspberrypi dhcpcd[385]: eth0: leased 192.168.0.100 for 86400 seconds
Apr  6 20:50:06 raspberrypi dhcpcd[385]: eth0: adding route to 192.168.0.0/24
Apr  6 20:50:06 raspberrypi dhcpcd[385]: eth0: adding default route via 192.168.0.1
Apr  6 20:50:06 raspberrypi dhcpcd[385]: forked to background, child pid 716
Apr  6 20:50:06 raspberrypi systemd[1]: Started dhcpcd on all interfaces.
Apr  6 20:50:06 raspberrypi ntpd[757]: Listen normally on 3 eth0 192.168.0.100 UDP 123
Apr  6 20:50:06 raspberrypi ntpd[757]: Listen normally on 5 eth0 2a02:c7d:2bbb:9f00:76b3:47f9:2c11:fea4 UDP 123
Apr  6 20:50:06 raspberrypi ntpd[757]: Listen normally on 6 eth0 fe80::1073:c87:ef15:c4a3 UDP 123
Apr  6 20:50:06 raspberrypi ntpd[757]: Listen normally on 8 eth0 fd41:6d80:6364:0:bcdf:ae43:354b:1e46 UDP 123
```

Answer (score 2):

Your if-up.d script will be executed more than once. The variable **$ADDRFAM** will be set to "**inet**" and "**inet6**" respectivy for when IPv4 and IPv6 is configured. Check for this variable in your script, if using bash:

```
[ "$ADDRFAM" == "inet6" ] || exit 0
```

(Note: this happens if you have a static IPv6 address configured, possibly not if using just SLAAC or DHCPv6, I did not test)

Comment: I checked this; but it's never inet6 (!) only inet, and all instances of it (it runs for each interface) occur way before DHCP is complete :(

Comment: I tested this on my Debian 8 box before posting - however, that particular box does have a static IPv6 address, so that might be why the behavior is different.

Comment: Probably; I guess there's no delay with a static IP, but DHCP is super-slow :( In the Pi forums I was told ifup is not a good place for this (and will always run before DHCP completes), and that I need to hook completion of DHCP. Gonna give that a go; I guess there's a lot of mis-information about when if-up fires on SO! :)